# Nightwatch edit the textbox and refill it

Tags: unit-testing

i am getting edit functionality check in nightwatch. 
empty the pre filled textbox and then edit that
how to do this any idea.

my code looks like

```
<p>editPatient_inputs:function(browser,editpatientval) {
        var editpatientid = editpatientval.setvaluesonelement.patientId;
        console.log(editpatientid);
        browser
            .waitForElementVisible(editpatientval.waitforelementvisible.previousbutton,8000)
            .click("a[data-patientid="+'"'+ editpatientval.patientsid.patientid +'"'+"]")
            .waitForElementVisible("form[id="+'"'+editpatientval.waitforelementvisible.form+'"'+"]", 5000)
            .waitForElementVisible('input[id=patientId]', 1000)
            .pause(1000)
            .execute(function(){
                //document.getElementsByName(editpatientval.setvaluesonelement.patientId).value="";
                document.getElementById(editpatientid).value="";
                document.getElementById(editpatientid).value="EditedId";
            })


    }</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Selenium Webdriver Functions for this.

```
    .clearValue( 'input[id=patientId]')
    .setValue( 'input[id=patientId]', 'your_text')
```

Comment: thanks for the help ...i used the same.it fixes all.